# Wait until an external operation completes with setInterval before finishing

Tags: javascript, async-await, setinterval

I got a JS code that simply activates a method. This method invokes an HTTP request which is causing some remote process to begin. I then need to check every 5 seconds if the remote process ended with a timeout of 5 minutes, after which I need to stop the waiting and throw an error if the timeout had expired, otherwise I need to simply log the result and complete the method.

What I'm not sure is how do I stop the execution of the main method until I get the response so I can have a value to log. This is what I got so far:

```
(async function(param) 
{
    ...
    var res = await fetch(...); //activate the remote proccess
    var textAnswer = await res.text();
    var infoObj = JSON.parse(textAnswer);
    startChecks(infoObj.info.id); // this is the method which I need to await on somehow 
}("paramValue");

async function startChecks(id)
{
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    intervalId = setInterval(checkStatus, 5000, id, startTime);
    
}

async function checkStatus(id, startTime)
{
  //if more than 5 minutes had passed
  if(new Date().getTime() - startTime > 300000) 
  {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      throw new Error("External pipeline timeout expired");
  }
  var res = await fetch(...); //check remote process
  var ans = await res.text();
  var obj = JSON.parse(ans);
  if(obj.finished) clearInterval(intervalId);
 }
```

Like I said, what I want to achieve is that my main function won't end until all intervals are done with either the error thrown or the process finishes. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create a helper function that executes your function in given intervals until it resolves to something different than `undefined`. But only for the maximum amount of time.

This could look something like this:

```js
// helper to wait for time milliseconds
async function sleep(time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

async function repeatedExecution(callback, interval, timeout) {
  // get start time
  const start = Date.now();

  // repeat as long the start time + timout is larger then the current time
  while (start + timeout > Date.now()) {
    // get a promise that resolves in interval seconds
    let sleeper = sleep(interval)

    // execute the callback
    let res
    if (res = await callback()) {
      // if the callback returns something truthy return it
      return res;
    }
    // wait until time for interval ends and then continue the loop
    await sleeper;
  }

  // if we reach this point we timed out
  throw new Error('timed out');
}


async function run() {
  /*
   var res = await fetch(...); //activate the remote proccess
   var textAnswer = await res.text();
   var infoObj = JSON.parse(textAnswer);
  */


  try {
    let result = await repeatedExecution(() => {
      /*
        var res = await fetch(...); //check remote process
        var ans = await res.text();
        var obj = JSON.parse(ans);
      
        if(obj.finished) {
          return true
        }
      */
    }, 1000, 3000);

    // do something on success
  } catch (err) {
    // handle the error (timeout case)
    console.error(err)
  }

}

run();
```

Comment: Even though it seems fine and easy to implement, is there a version of it which uses setInterval?

Comment: @YonatanNir why do you want to use `setInterval`? The shown code does the same as if you would use `setInterval`.

Comment: Trying to avoid changing my code. Not that its too difficult but still..

Comment: @YonatanNir `Trying to avoid changing my code.` you in some way need to add the logic that you can wait in the main code. The way you do with `setTimeout` and `setInterval` is pretty similar. The code is just clearer with the use of `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. There is not really much to rewrite.

Comment: @YonatanNir added to comment blocks to show where your code would be moved to.

Comment: in the while condition, is the timeout supposed to be a MS value? I didn't know you can add a date to a MS value and get a new date

Comment: @YonatanNir `is the timeout supposed to be a MS value? ` the timeout and interval are milliseconds (like it is the case for `setTimeout` and `setInterval()`). `I didn't know you can add a date to a MS value and get a new date` you don't get a new date, [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) returns the current moment as a representation in milliseconds, so you work on values representing moments in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.